# How can i store this text data in array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have some text data which i would want into a json array format, but i dont know how do i split the text

i tried it witch str_replace but no good result

This is the text data:

```
IP Address: 141.101.104.169
Country: Germany
State: North Rhine-Westphalia
City: Neuss
Latitude: 51.1981
Longitude: 6.6850000000000005
```

It is just text on my site. But i want it in json format like this:

```
{
  "IP_Address": "141.101.104.169",
  "Country": "Germany",
  "State": "North Rhine-Westphalia",
  "City": "Neuss",
  "Latitude": "51.1981",
  "Longitude": "6.6850000000000005",
}
```

Is that possible with any php function or methode? It would be great if you could post some examples based on my situation.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are the names fixed - some are more difficult if not (IP Address has a space and so difficult to know when to split).

Comment: Year the names are fit because i get it from an external site, but the values behind the names can swtiching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to explode data line based and string based. You can use `explode('\n', $str);` to parse lines.

```
$data = 'IP Address: 141.101.104.169
Country: Germany
State: North Rhine-Westphalia
City: Neuss
Latitude: 51.1981
Longitude: 6.6850000000000005';

$lines = explode("\n", $data);

foreach($lines as $line_number => $line){
  $line_to_data = explode(": ", $line);
  $key = $line_to_data[0];
  $value = $line_to_data[1];
  $array[] = array($key => $value );
}

$json = json_encode($array);
print_r($json);
```

Result:

```
[
{
"IP Address":"141.101.104.169\r"
},
{
"Country":"Germany\r"
},
{
"State":"North Rhine-Westphalia\r"
},
{
"City":"Neuss\r"
},{
"Latitude":"51.1981\r"
},{
"Longitude":"6.6850000000000005"
}
]
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple way of doing this is to use `explode()`, once to split it into the separate lines, then to split it into tag/value parts...

```
$input = 'IP Address: 141.101.104.169
Country: Germany
State: North Rhine-Westphalia
City: Neuss
Latitude: 51.1981
Longitude: 6.6850000000000005';

$output = [];
foreach ( explode(PHP_EOL, $input) as $line )   {
    list($tag,$value) = explode(":", $line, 2);
    $output[trim($tag)] = trim($value);
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 2):

For your example data, one option could be to match all until the first `:` and the rest in a second part using a pattern with [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and 2 capturing groups.

```
^([^:]+)\h*:\h*(.*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([^:]+)` Group 1, capture matching 1+ times any char but :
- `\h*:\h*` Match `:` between horizontal whitespace chars
- `(.*)` Capture group 2, match any char 0+ times except a newline

For example

```
$data = <<<DATA
IP Address: 141.101.104.169
Country: Germany
State: North Rhine-Westphalia
City: Neuss
Latitude: 51.1981
Longitude: 6.6850000000000005
DATA;

preg_match_all("~^([^:]+)\h*:\h*(.*)~m", $data, $matches);
$result = json_encode(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
print_r($result);
```

Result

```
{
  "IP Address": "141.101.104.169",
  "Country": "Germany",
  "State": "North Rhine-Westphalia",
  "City": "Neuss",
  "Latitude": "51.1981",
  "Longitude": "6.6850000000000005"
}
```

Comment: Awesome i m so glad thank you it works perfectly for my needs. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_encode('data to encode as json object')

`$outputdata = json_encode($data)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `serialize($array)` to cast array on string and `unserialize($array)` to cast string into array